# How to get value from stop observable in takeUntil

Tags: javascript, reactive-programming, rxjs5

I'm doing something similar though not exactly like drag and drop. I want to click > track movement for a preview > stop tracking on click again > get metadata from last click. But, users can click on multiple things to stop tracking and I want to know what it was since the side effects are different depending on the second item clicked.

Basically, its

```
clickSomething$ = merge(anythingTheyCanClick);
click$.switchMap(click => moveData.takeUntil(clickSomething$)) //need to get value from clickSomething$
```

This is a specific request for getting the value from a stop observable in takeUntill, but if that's not possible or impractical, an inclusive buffer or window technique (e.g. buffer/window on click, but keep the clicks) could also solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can merge all stopper observable together (obsStop$), map the first stop event to distinguish it from mousemove, take only one such event and concat with dummy 'close - takeUntil' event. takeWhile will take all mouse movements and close event till dummy 'close - takeUntil' event come.

```
  let start = document.getElementById('start');
  let stop1 = document.getElementById('stop1');
  let stop2 = document.getElementById('stop2');
  let stop3 = document.getElementById('stop3');

  let start$ = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(start, 'click');
  let stop1$ = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(stop1, 'click');
  let stop2$ = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(stop2, 'click');
  let stop3$ = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(stop3, 'click');

  let obsStop$ = Rx.Observable.merge(stop1$, stop2$, stop3$);

  start$.switchMap(x => {
    return Rx.Observable.fromEvent(document, 'mousemove')
      .merge(obsStop$
        .map(event => {
          return {stopClick: true, event: event};
        })
        .take(1)
        .concat(Rx.Observable.of('takeUntil')))
      .takeWhile(x => x !== 'takeUntil')

  }).subscribe(x => console.log(x));
```